# Skip sub-directories using grunt-clean

Tags: gruntjs

I am writing a grunt-contrib-clean script and want to delete all the sub-directories in a directory excluding two directories. Following is the directory structure:

```
/resources/nls/ar
/resources/nls/ar-AE
/resources/nls/ca
/resources/nls/ca-ES
/resources/nls/en
/resources/nls/en-US
/resources/nls/localeElements.js
```

and so on for all the locales.

I want to keep only the `en`, `en-US` directories and the file `localeElements.js`. I am using the following Grunt script. The single file in "nls" folder is not deleted as desired. But it deletes all the folders inside including the `en` & `en-US` folders which I don't want. Please guide and help.

```
clean: {
  postBuildSizeReduction: [
    '!../resources/nls/en/**',
    '!../resources/nls/en-US/**',
    '../resources/nls/*/'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the directories listed, so that the deletions come first, followed by the exclusions.

```
clean: {
    postBuildSizeReduction: [
        '../resources/nls/',
        '!../resources/nls/en', 
        '!../resources/nls/en-US'
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried this sequence as well but its not working..it deletes all the directories under nls. Only the file in nls directory is not deleted.

Comment: @AsifMahmood - I've just made a minor edit to remove the `*/` at the end of the first glob path. Try removing that and see how you go.